# Why Google PageSpeed Insight Shows some images in Opportunities even after adding lazyloading on the images

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I have searched for this everywhere but I don't think there is anything written yet for this.

Every week I optimize 1 to 2 Shopify and WordPress sites. When Google shows images in "Defer offscreen images" in the opportunities section I usually add https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes in shopify.

I have noticed one thing sometimes even after adding lazyloding to the images google still shows some images in "Defer offscreen images" in the opportunities section whereas it should not show them.

I'm sure if you have optimized the speed of multiple sites you would have also noticed this problem.

Comment: care to share an example speed test run / site URL this is happening on.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Here are the screenshots
http://prntscr.com/qfw5vf - Google insight
http://prntscr.com/qfw87l - Lazyload added in code

Comment: looks ok from screenshots, want to share the URL with me and I will have a poke around for you, the problem with seeing the end result is that I can't see the flow to see if it is something 'not obvious'

Comment: thank you for checking the screenshots, here is the link, pls see if you can find something https://hqz1uhw33yeg8guk-24446637.shopifypreview.com/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with Google Page Speed Insights, it is with your implementation / your plugin.

Take the following as an example (part of the brand images section):-

```
<td>
    <a href="https://www.primemassagechairs.com/collections/ultracomfort-america" title="UltraComfort America">
        <div style="text-align: left;">
            <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2444/6637/files/UltraComfort_Logo_Home_Page_Image.jpg?v=1553734908" alt="Ultra Comfort Lift Chairs" width="" height="" style="float: none;">
        </div>
    </a>
</td>
```

The plugin is not recognising this as an image to be lazy loaded (or you have not adjusted it for lazy loading as per the instructions on the plugin - I am not familiar with the plugin to know what you are meant to do here).

As a `src` is set for this image it will be downloaded normally and that is why Page Speed Insights is marking this as a problem.

As far as I can tell the correct format for this should be

```
<img data-src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2444/6637/files/UltraComfort_Logo_Home_Page_Image.jpg?v=1553734908" class="lazyload" alt="Ultra Comfort Lift Chairs" width="" height="" style="float: none;"/>
```

with the image URL as the `data-src` and a class of `lazyload` in order for the plugin to work and no `href` set.

Either manually adjust this or find another plugin.

As a final thought - the way this plugin is implemented means that if the site has no JavaScript the images will not load at all, it may be worth exploring a better option that provides a `<noscript>` fallback for the images (or adding them yourself).

Comment: The plugin is implemented correctly and it is working fine for some of the images as well. Actually you are checking it on live site and I have implemented it on a copy theme. I have sent you the link for the copy theme where it is implemented in my previous comment.

Comment: The fact it works for some images and you believe it to be implemented correctly says that it doesn't pick up everything automatically and you need to manually adjust the ones it isn't picking up. The example I gave is not functioning as a lazy loaded image so my guess is because it is contained in a table it is ignored by your plugin. Change it manually as per my suggestion and see if it then gets loaded lazily. Not seen a link from you, where did you send it?

Comment: Here is the site link again https://hqz1uhw33yeg8guk-24446637.shopifypreview.com/

And here you can see in the screenshot it is implemented fine but google still showing those images in results. https://prnt.sc/qfw5vf and https://prnt.sc/qfw87l

Comment: so when you look at the waterfall (with a throttled connection) those slides are being loaded several times (as instead of storing the slide image it reloads it 3 times). Page Speed Insights is interpreting this as an image that is not lazy loaded correctly as it is not needed for the initial page load (i.e. slide_1 is showing, it loads in slide_2 but it is not visible so it considers that to not be lazy loaded as your page is still loading). Everything else I said is true, that is why you are seeing that behaviour, get a slider that only loads the first image before the page is initialised.